# How to create a horizontal legend?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3.js how can I create a horizontal legend with 2 rows?

This is current JavaScript code that creates a legend:

```
var legendGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(width-50)+",30)");

  var legend = legendGroup.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(nations.map(d=>d.name))
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", (d,i)=>"translate(0," + 20*i + ")")

  var legendRects = legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 10)
        .attr("fill", d=> colorScale(d));

  var legendText = legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 14)
        .attr("y", 8)
    .text(d=>d);
```

Comment: Does this effectively create a single, legend row?

Comment: @HimmelIt creates a column, I would say so. So, now it's vertically aigned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code you posted is a column, as you stated, because it translates each piece of the legend 20 pixels below the last: `"translate(0," + 20*i + ")"`. By manipulating the translate statement you can create a 2 row legend if you know how many elements are in your array, though even if you don't, you can specify how many elements can be in each row.

In the following code block, `n` refers to how many items should be in a row, `itemWidth` a pixel value for the width of each legend entry, and `itemHeight` the height.

I don't know how many legend items you have, but you could set it up as such:

```
.attr("transform", function(d,i) { return 
               "translate(" + i%n * itemWidth + 
               "," +
               Math.floor(i/n) * itemHeight + ")"; })
```

This should work like so:

```js
var data = ["Cat A","Cat B","Cat C", "Cat D", "Dog A", "Dog B", "Dog C", "Dog D"];
var n = data.length/2;
var itemWidth =80;
var itemHeight = 18;

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var color = d3.scale.category10();


var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + i%n * itemWidth + "," + Math.floor(i/n) * itemHeight + ")"; })
 .attr("class","legend");
 
var rects = legend.append('rect')
 .attr("width",15)
 .attr("height",15)
 .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); });
 
var text = legend.append('text')
 .attr("x", 15)
 .attr("y",12)
 .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

---

Edit:
Here's a snippet moving the entire horizontal legend (using four rows to show the movement better to the right side better in this narrow view) based on the comment below:

```js
var data = ["Cat A","Cat B","Cat C", "Cat D", "Dog A", "Dog B", "Dog C", "Dog D"];
var n = data.length/4;
var itemWidth =80;
var itemHeight = 18;
var width = 500;

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var legendGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+(width-150)+",10)");

var legend = legendGroup.selectAll(".legend")
 .data(data)
 .enter()
 .append("g")
 .attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + i%n * itemWidth + "," + Math.floor(i/n) * itemHeight + ")"; })
 .attr("class","legend");
 
var rects = legend.append('rect')
 .attr("width",15)
 .attr("height",15)
 .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); });
 
var text = legend.append('text')
 .attr("x", 15)
 .attr("y",12)
 .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="500" height="200"> </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I move this legend to the right corner?

Comment: You could combine the snippet above with the first lines of your code: 

`var legendGroup = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+(width-50)+",30)");`.  

The -50 pulls the legend back 50 pixels from the right (and the 30 pulls the legend 30 down from the top). You would probably want to pull the legend further right than -50 with a horizontal legend as this marks the leftmost portion of the legend. 

Then instead of `var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")` use `var legend = legendGroup.selectAll(".legend")`.

Comment: Ok, this is clear. So, which parameter do you use to control the number of raws? What if I want to create 3 or 4 raws instead of 2?

Comment: If you want to modify the number of rows you can change the number of items that appear in each row, which in my example is `n`. If I was dealing with a data array of variable length, then I should make sure that the method I used to determine `n` rounds down or up so that placement is regular (since the method I used could produce a non-integer, which would mess with item placement). I've edited the answer to include an example with 4 rows and whole legend movement

Answer (score 5):

```
const legendData = ['The United States', 'Brazil', 'India', 'China', 'United Arab Emirates']  // The names which you want to appear as legends should be inside this array.

const legend = d3.select('svg')
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (margin.left + margin.right + 60) + ',' + (margin.top - 20) + ')')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(legendData)
  .enter()
  .append('g');

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('fill', (d, i) => color(d))     //   const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  .attr('height', 15)
  .attr('width', 15);

legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', 18)
  .attr('y', 10)
  .attr('dy', '.15em')
  .text((d, i) => d)
  .style('text-anchor', 'start')
  .style('font-size', 12);

// Now space the groups out after they have been appended:
const padding = 10;
legend.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
  return 'translate(' + (d3.sum(legendData, function (e, j) {
    if (j < i) { return legend.nodes()[j].getBBox().width; } else { return 0; }
  }) + padding * i) + ',0)';
});
```